# Sending logs and metrics from ECS Fargate containers to Datadog

Tags: logging, monitoring, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, datadog

We are exploring to use Datadog as an end target for our Fargate logs and JVM application metrics. On doing some research we explored, we will have to run a sidecar for Datadog agent which will collect metrics and send to Datadog. Similarly we will have to spin up [another sidecar container for logs as it needs to be done through Fluentbit](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/aws-fargate-monitoring-with-datadog/) router container using AWS firelens drivers.

I am still not sure for:

- Whether we can run both sidecars simultaneously with application
  container.
- Will running both sidecar containers be resource intensive and affect
  overall task resources
- Is there any other option or way to do it more effectively?

PS: I am ruling out the lambda collection through Cloudwatch approach.

Answer (score 2):

> - Whether we can run both sidecars simultaneously with application container.

ECS supports [up to 10 containers per task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-quotas.html). So you can have up to 9 sidecar containers.

> - Will running both sidecar containers be resource intensive and affect overall task resources

I doubt it. The only way to know for sure is to test it and see. But those sidecars shouldn't be using the CPU very much, they are just sending some bits of info to DataDog periodically.

> - Is there any other option or way to do it more effectively?
>
> PS: I am ruling out the lambda collection through Cloudwatch approach.

No, there isn't another approach. You are following the DataDog recommended implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda collection will cost you more and for that also you have to route the logs to aws cloudwatch via a side car container anyways and then push them to datadog via lambda.

Yes sidecar is the recommended approach we are running a firelens log-router container and data-agent sidecar container. However, we have pinned log-router to max 50 of memory limit.